# What kind of Javascript notation / shortcut is this?

Tags: javascript

Came across the following on someone's site and I'm curious to understand the shortcut applied here. I simplified the variables for demo purposes.

```
 function(){
      _imaboolean || ($element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible"), this.imaboolean = !0)
 }
```

Same thing with

```
this._imaboolean && ($element.removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden"), this._imaboolean = !1)
```

Comment: Too "clever" and confusing.

Comment: The spacing is great though, if you read it out loud

Comment: @user2246674 poor readability of this example notwithstanding, it's fairly idiomatic JS, as the sheer number of SO questions suggests.

Comment: @MattBall Unfortunately .. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is some *awful* "clever" code, however, let's decompose it!

```
_imaboolean || ($element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible"), this.imaboolean = !0)
```

First, let's replace all the expressions with placeholders (note these expressions are *not* pure and have side-effects):

```
a || (b, c)
```

Note that `||` is short-circuiting such that the right expression - `(b, c)` - will only be evaluated if `a` evaluates to a false-y value.

So, let's assume that `a` evaluates to a false-y value, then `(b, c)` is evaluated. In this case the `,` operator separates sub-expressions; all the sub-expressions are evaluated in order. The result of the expression is the result of the last sub-expression.

This means it is roughly equivalent to (although there is no function or binding context and the result is thrown out anyway):

```
(function () { b; return c })()
```

Did that make sense? No, of course not!

Write it like you mean it:

```
if (!_imaboolean) {
  $element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
  this.imaboolean = true; // get rid of !0 too
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Extremely clear example!!!

Answer (score 2):

This code can be inflated to:

```
function() {
    if (!this.imaboolean) {
        $element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
        this.imaboolean = true;
    }
}
```

The `||` is used as a short circuit, if `imaboolean` is `true` it will break out, however if it's `false` it will execute the remaining portion of the expression. `!0` is a minified way of saying `true` (because `0` evaluates to `false` in a boolean expression).

Comment: why `!0`, `1` would be a more minified and more straighforward way for true

Comment: @gbitmmon Because `1` is not a boolean expression and therefore evaluates to `1` when `!0` evaluates to `false` - a boolean value. That is why.

Comment: @gbtimmon `!0 !== 1; 1 !== true; !0 === true` - that is, 1 is not a direct replacement for !0. The previous comment contains an error (it should have been "!0 evaluates to true"), but had the idea correct. While truth-y/false-y *usually* works as intended, there are subtle differences - consider jQuery.extend where the first parameter can be an object or a boolean.

Comment: @user2246674 I don't buy it. `1` is just as truthy and `0` is falsey.
Try `1||alert('test');` and see what happens. `1` is considered true there. And (!0 == 1) doesnt matter. There is an implict cast to boolean in the `||` operator so what you are concerned with is `toBoolean(!0) === toBoolean(1)` which is always true.

Comment: @gbtimmon Which is why I used `!==` and `===` explicitly to discuss the nuance.

Comment: @gbtimmon I did not say that it's `!0` is a shorthand for a "truthy" value, I said it's shorthand for `true`. `!0` is a standard minification for the hardcoded `true`. Try something like `one = true;` and compile with the closure compiler on "Simple" you'll get `one=!0`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is short for

```
 function(){
      if( ! _imaboolean){
         $element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");
         this.imaboolean = true; 
     }
 }
```

Its also generally terrible coding in my opinion and should not be copied.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's terrible, it looks minified. In which case the source is probably not written that way.

Comment: @izuriel it doesn't look minified... This is not how minified code look.

Comment: Even if it isn't minified, "terrible" is a stretch. "Harder to maintain", maybe, but "terrible"? Nah. It isn't `eval`.

Comment: I'm of the school that hard to maintain == terrible, but like i said, thats my opinion.

Comment: @gbtimmon Not sure what site it was scrapped from but it was pulled from a site and modified for demo purposes (as the asker stated). Other than that, I've seen this done commonly when a more complex minification process is used like the Closure Compiler. But I was just making the statement to provide a secondary argument against the code being "terrible" which it definitely is not if it's been minified.

Comment: If it minified, why is the var name still _imaboolean. Var shorting is the most effective minification and the easiest. Whay refactor code but not refactor var names ?!?!. That what leads me to believe its not minified.

Comment: The key point of was that the person asking the question has already modified the source for demo purposes. You're not looking at the original, you're looking at a modified sample. Why would someone name their boolean value `imaboolean` - that's extremely helpful and readable code.

Answer (score 0):

It's a short-circuit evaluation where the second part will only be evaluated if the first part fails.

Answer (score 0):

```
function(){
      _imaboolean || ($element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible"), this.imaboolean = !0)
 }
```

Let's break this down. First we see the `||` operator, so we have `(statement) || (anotherStatement)`. The way `||` works is that it evaluates the first statement. If that evaluates to true, it short-circuits and does not evaluate the second statement. The first statement is just `_imaboolean`. If that's a truthy value (i.e., not 0 or false or undefined...), then we stop right there and don't go to the second statement.

The second statement is

```
($element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible"), this.imaboolean = !0)
```

Again, there's two statements, separated by a comma. The comma operator evaluates BOTH statements, and returns the last one. So it evaluates `$element.removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible")` (which sets some classes on $element), and then it evaluates `this.imaboolean = !0` (which sets this.imaboolean to a truthy value). The next time this function is run, it will short circuit due to the `||` operator.